# How do I use SFML on Apple M1 Mac?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, sfml, apple-m1, rosetta-2

I installed SFML for macOS-clang with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOyp5n2FmZY. And I setup the Xcode like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kusRtYC-wj4 but it does not work like in the video. It can be built with no error or warning but when I run [this is what happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c9lx.png) Just so you guys know that

1. I am an amateur.
2. I use MacBook Pro M1 2020.
3. I never work with SFML before.
4. I just start using Xcode. I am used to work on VSCode before.
5. I got Rosetta2 installed.
6. Before this I have tried to do it on VSCode with this Boilerplate(https://github.com/andrew-r-king/sfml-vscode-boilerplate.git).
7. I also have tried SFML that install via Homebrew.

What should I do? I really need to do this because I have to use it to make my game project for my college. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: "this is what happen": Please do not link to screen shots but instead add the output as text to your questions. Also see: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

First, install SFML with brew.

```
brew install sfml
```

Get location information

```
brew info sfml
```

You will see /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.X.Y in the output. It is the location for headers, lib, etc.

Compile with

```
g++ main.cpp -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/include -o app -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Last step is:

```
./app
```

Done!

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application");
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    shape.setRadius(40.f);
    shape.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For  M1 macs

1. setup all the paths:

Header Search Paths
Libary Search Paths

You can add the path to the homebrew installation.

2. Pay attention for what MacOS version you are building. For MacOS 11.0 and bellow, the only option is to use rosetta...
3. If your mac has a AppleSilicon, installing sfml with brew will generate arm64 libraries for you. So will need to update the MacOS version in your project and choose the correct test platform in the upper bar, inside Xcode, you should have MyProject > My Mac (Rosetta) or MyProject > My Mac, just Choose "My Mac" if you are using brew.